# Is it possible to run a Chrome extension in the Edge web browser?

Tags: browser, web, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge

I wanted to create an extension for the Edge web browser, and I have a Chrome extension related to it.

Is it possible to run a Chrome extension in the Edge web browser?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Update (2016-03-19)

Not *yet*, but Edge decided to support the roughly the same WebExtensions model as Firefox - partial compatibility with Chrome extensions. They will be offered through Windows Store.

Edge has started rolling out experimental extension support. This is [currently in Insider Preview builds](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/03/17/preview-extensions/) and an extremely closed platform preview / closed beta. See also [updated FAQs](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/faq/#extensions).

Some choice Twitter quotes from devs:

Jacob Rossi [on porting extensions](https://twitter.com/jacobrossi/status/710881562846306304)

> Lots of questions on this: yes we're working on a porting tool to run Chrome extensions in Edge. Not yet finished and not all APIs supported

Jacob Rossi [on Store accessibility for developers](https://twitter.com/jacobrossi/status/710884508367597568)

> extn's in Store will at first be a carefully selected set covering top scenarios and API coverage, opening up to more in future

Kyle Pflug [on sideloading non-Store extensions](https://twitter.com/kylealden/status/710889278771888128)

> We'll allow side-loading after launch, but will require dev mode toggle & will have appropriate warnings in UI

Comment: In the (distant) future: "Edge [...] will introduce support for a new type of [...] extensions that are almost identical to Chrome’s. With only a few tweaks, developers will be able to bring their extensions to the new browser." ([source](http://9to5google.com/2015/04/29/microsoft-edge-chrome-extensions/))

Comment: @wOxxOm Cool, didn't know that. Edited.

Comment: So do we have to make extensions for edge browser specifically?

Comment: @Sameera For now, yes. How long is "now", nobody knows. Same with Firefox, but the approximate date when the switch happens is known.

Comment: @wOxxOm,@ Xan Thank you very much

Comment: while there is no official edge timeline, i noticed that some chrome.* APIs are already defined in edge while testing last week. cool.

Comment: @SameeraLiyanage Bad news, Edge FAQ says that there's no way to make an extension for Edge yet.

Comment: @Xan, yesterday (3/17/2016) it was [announced](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/03/17/preview-extensions/)  that the first set of extensions for Microsoft Edge were available to preview via the Windows Insider Program. It would be great if you could update the answer.